# What is a "Low Difficulty Share" error?

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-pools, difficulty-share

I am trying to mine on an old **AMD Radeon HD 57xx** GPU with Catalyst version **15.7.1** on a Windows10 x64 machine.
Claymore's CryptoNote GPU Miner v9.4 receives the following error from the pool

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":2.0","error":{"code":-1,"message":"Lowdifficultyshare"}}
```

[This topic on bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=638915.0) suggests to use a particular algorithm for such card (**-a 3** switch).

What does "Low Difficulty Share" error mean in this context?

Comment: I had the same problem, reverting to v8.0 solved the problem.

Comment: Also **-a 3** switch solves the problem on Claymore v9.4. I'm just wondering what this error actually is/mean.

Comment: According to the documentation - "-a 3" fastest mining for old cards (6xxx and 5xxx). In version 9.3 I kept getting this error even with this switch, and had to revert to 8.0. I didn't try yet v9.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually that error means the share your miner submitted was garbage, and didn't actually verify on the pool. Sometimes it means the share was submitted too late, and the pool has already moved on to the next block. But if you keep getting it over and over, then your miner code is broken (or you're using the wrong algorithm).